# Group by quarters annual

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I need to group by quarter year by year in my `.php` file. In **bold** type I show the code that needs to be fixed aka switch case 4. Just now I group correct for year, month, week and day, but now I need quarter name case 4. I tried this code for `GROUP FUNCTION`, but is shows me 5 groups in 2010 and 2011 and this is wrong.

```
switch ($level) 
{

  case '4':**
    $group = "FLOOR(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(invoice_date))/3)";</b>
    break;
}
```

FIXED IS

```
SQL PART


case '4':
                    $group = "EXTRACT(YEAR FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(invoice_date)) as group_field2, EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(invoice_date))";
                    break;

    $sql_select = $db->query("SELECT sum(amount) AS invoice_amount, " . $group . " AS group_field FROM 
                " . DB_PREFIX . "invoices WHERE invoice_date>= " . $startup . " " . $user_query . " GROUP BY group_field, group_field2 ORDER BY group_field2 DESC, group_field DESC");


TEXT - LINK PART

                    case '4':
                        $start = strtotime('+' . (($view_details_received['group_field'] - 1) * 3) . ' months', strtotime($view_details_received['group_field2'] . '/1/1'));
                        $finish = strtotime('+' . (($view_details_received['group_field'] - 1) * 3 + 3) . ' months', strtotime($view_details_received['group_field2'] . '/1/1'));
                        $start = getdate($start);
                        $finish = getdate($finish - 86400);
                        $title = 'Q' . $view_details_received['group_field2'] . ', ' . $view_details_received['group_field'];
                        break;
```

Comment: What is that error you're referring to?

Comment: thanks DAN

in case4 part of mysql i use function FLOOR

for group by quarter but the result

see screenshot here http://i48.tinypic.com/2z56smp.gif

not as correct for year 2010 and 2011 where the quarter are strange 5

Comment: YEAR_MONTH will give you results like 201101. Dividing that by 3 doesn't make much sense. I think you're looking for something to replace YEAR_MONTH.

Comment: yes DAN i need to group my invoice by quarter.. like 4 quarters for 2012, 4 quarters for 2011 and soo.. but i not know how to :-(
YEAR_MONTH is an idea but is bad idea.. any suggestion please..

Answer (score 2):

You can use EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date) in your SQL and then do regular GROUP BY

See [EXTRACT documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract)  on MySQL webpage and [table of possible arguments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) to it.

Comment: thank Kamil

but EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date) not as correct for me

because group me all quarters of all years

example show me

q1 ( from 2010+2011+2012)
q2 ( from 2010+2011+2012)
q3 ( from 2010+2011+2012)
q4 ( from 2010+2011+2012)

i need group by quarter year by year

q1 ( from 2012)
q2 ( from 2012)
q3 ( from 2012)
q4 ( from 2012)
q1 ( from 2011)

Comment: Why not use two arguments to group by? Like: GROUP BY EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)... this should give you specific group for each quarter in each year in your dataset...

Comment: thx Kamil but the result of 2 arguments group me only by the second argument aka group by only by year

code i use

<pre>
     $group = "EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(invoice_date)), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(invoice_date))";

</pre>

result correct is for all my 3 year a total of 12 quartes but is only 4 : Jan. 18, 2012 
Nov. 14, 2011 
Sep. 20, 2010 
Jan. 20, 2009

Comment: how to i can passed 2 argumets both

Comment: Looks like you're using some framework? You need to find out how to enter more complex group by clause... anyhow - I'm not getting the background idea of your app - why do you name the date "Jan 18, 2012" to be a quarter? It's not and will never be... quarter is like 1/2012...

Comment: thx Kamil, i use notepad++ not a framework, the first part of code is for mysql and group, the second part of code is for php and create the name and link: i can change second part in to       $title = date("Q, Y", $view_details_received['invoice_date']);

than i see Q, 2012... // the part for name and link arrive in second time.. first problem is get 4 group for 2012, 4 groups for 2011 etc etc.. with my first code floor+YEAR_MONTH+ /3.. the result is not good - now i want try to use your idea aka passed 2 arguments.. but i not know how to, because track only one arguments

Comment: I don't know how you deal with the variables set in the code parts quoted in your question - if you pass two conditions to GROUP BY, separated by comma (,) it has to work. Can you show me how does the output look like when you select "Monthly" view? ...also note, that you cannot just put group by to query like SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY ... it'll most likely not do what you want and all good DB servers will refuse to accept such queries. mysql does accept it, but it's wrong and probably source of your problem

Comment: than for example : part 1 of code is mysql and group by month
CODE :  <pre> case '3':
    $group = "EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(invoice_date))";
    break;</pre>
part 2 of code is for link and name example october 2012, if i click it i go to a full list of invoices in the time from 1 october to 30 october, and the code for it is
CODE
<pre>
  case '3':
    $start = getdate($view_details_received['invoice_date']);
   see code in my question header... case 3
</pre>

now i need first (mysql) group by quarter than (php) name and link for quarter grouped.. T H A N K S

Comment: The query should be: SELECT EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(invoice_date)) as QUARTER, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(invoice_date)) as YEAR, SUM(invoice_amount) as TOTAL FROM invoices GROUP BY EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(invoice_date)), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(invoice_date)) ORDER BY  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(invoice_date)), EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(invoice_date)) - then when fetching data in your PHP, just get the $title as eg. $result->QUARTER . '/' . $result->YEAR and display the $result->TOTAL in the corresponding row...

Comment: hi try give me 1 minutes... and see above i put ALL my FULL code, part for mysql, for php and for link.. than you can help me better :-) thanks

Comment: One last try before editing it by myself - the problem is in aliasing of the group by clause... set the $group = "EXTRACT(YEAR FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(invoice_date) as group_field2, EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(invoice_date)" and in your queries adjust the "GROUP BY group_field" to be "GROUP BY group_field, group_field2"

Comment: Heh, I just replied - but you're on the good path! You need to add group_field2 to the order by... and then fix the $title... both is done in the code send to you per email...

Comment: HI KAMIL.. i'm back and you.. we can end my request help? THX